# How to compare just the date part of a dateTime field?

Tags: datetime

Ok I want to list event entries based on the start date of those events.

I have a route set up which provides the date in the same format as held in the start date field. But trying to compare this with:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('events').startDate(date) %}
```

to pull out only entries for the specified date fails as the date variable only holds the date portion of the startDate field i.e. 2015-10-02 and not the time segment.

So is there some way I can format this call so that the comparison is like with like without the time segment. I have tried a few things with filters but nothing is working.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I'm reading your question correctly, but here goes:

I'm assuming you're getting the date as a string as a route param (maybe you shouldn't call it `date` though, as that is a function in Twig), I'll call that `dateTime` here:

`{% set dayAfter = date(datetime) | date_modify('+1 day') | date('Y-m-d') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').startDate(['and', '>= '~datetime, '< '~dayAfter]) %}`

What's happening is you get a date, then you add one day to that date, then find all entries that have `startDate` greater than or equal to the date you're looking for, *and* less than the day after, thus getting all entries for that particular date.

This might be over engineered though, and there might be a way simpler way to do this...

Comment: Thanks @megatrond works a treat. Although as you say does seem a little over engineered.